# Sprite - How to only touch certain parts of screen?

Tags: ios, touch, sprite-kit, sprite, area

I am making a game and I only want the user to touch the edges of the screen? Is there any way I can do this?

The following code lets the user touch anywhere on the screen but I would like them to only touch certain parts of the screen.

Thank You For Time And Answers

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wall"];

        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.scale = 0.5;
        sprite.name = @"wall"; // Needed For Release Thing
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;


        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4];
        SKAction *delete = [SKAction removeFromParent];


        SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, delete, ]];
        [sprite runAction: sequence];

        [self addChild:sprite];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt test this so I'm not sure if it will work

```
 for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if (((location.x < leftTouchArea) || (location.x > rightTouchArea)) && ((location.y < upperTouchArea) || (location.y > lowerTouchArea))) 
    {

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wall"];

        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.scale = 0.5;
        sprite.name = @"wall"; // Needed For Release Thing
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;


       SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4];
       SKAction *delete = [SKAction removeFromParent];


       SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, delete, ]];
       [sprite runAction: sequence];

       [self addChild:sprite];
    }

}
```

Comment: Even if it doesn't work your approach to solving this issue is entirely correct.